# AngularJS number $filter issue for numbers with 20 and 21 digits

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I use AngularJS $filter to format a number to 2 decimal places per the code below

```
$filter('number')(n, 2)
```

When 'n' is 20 or 21 digits long, the result of the above expression is NaN.

No issues when 'n' is less than 20 digits or more than 21 digits (for more than 21 digits, the above expression is displayed in scientific notation)

Any thoughts on how to fix the NaN issue for 20 and 21 digit numbers?

Comment: Fun question, I don't think it's likely for someone who isn't on the core team to know this. You should locate the source of that filter in the `angular` source and post it here

Comment: Link to the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filters.js#L129). It's rather long (if you step into the `formatNumber()` code, which is right below the filter's code).

Comment: Thank you for posting the link to source code. I also created an issue in the AngularJS github repo [link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11183)